# 'the back' or 'in the back'?

Tags: relative-pronouns

*I traveled in a truck the back of it the owner had loaded with potatoes.*

In this sentence, the book says we have to use 'which' instead of 'it'.
I understand that, but I think there should be 'in' or 'at' at the end of the sentence.

like,

*I traveled in a truck the back of it the owner had loaded with potatoes in.*

If it isn't, the sentence will be

*The owner had loaded with potatoes the back of the truck.*

Is the sentence also correct..?

Comment: Your original sentence reads as you posted it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The owner had loaded the back of the truck with potatoes.

is fine, in all forms of English, as far as I know. This uses the schema 'load *x* with *Y*.

Turning it round, as you have done to

> ? The owner had loaded with potatoes the back of the truck.

is odd, because a prepositional phrase does not usually come between the verb and its direct object; but it is comprehensible, and if the direct object is very long, it might be preferred:

> The owner had loaded with potatoes the back of his very ancient and rickety truck.

As the book says, we require a relative for a sentence with an embedded clause like that. So

> I travelled in a truck the back of which the owner had loaded with potatoes.

is fine, except that most people don't use phrases like *the back of which* in ordinary speech. You could reorder it to

> I travelled in a truck of which the owner had loaded the back with potatoes

but that would still be quite stilted. The usual spoken phrase for *the back of which* is *whose back* (even if it is something inanimate: *whose* means *of which* as well as *of whom*). But

> I travelled in a truck whose back the owner had loaded with potatoes.

still reads a bit oddly to me; I'm not sure why.

I would probably say

> I travelled in a truck where the owner had loaded the back with potatoes.

Whatever construction, if you're using the phrase "load ... with ... " you don't want *in*.

Answer (score 0):

**A poor sentence** to start with: 
I traveled in a truck the back of it the owner had loaded with potatoes.

can be this with **which**:

**I traveled in a truck the back of which the owner had loaded with potatoes**.